# RecycleList проблема с размером елементов списка

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, cardview, height

Написал я елемент с которого составляется `RecycleList` >> `CardViev` В самом `CardViev` есть скрытые элементы и есть видимые. При нажатии скрытые элементы появляются и увеличивают размер `CardViev` потому что высота его установлена  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` но крутя дальше по списку каждый 8 или 10 элемент списка имеет пустой `CardViev` размером как той на который нажали.  [image: На Фото будет наглядно видно.]

Как пофиксить этот баг что бы все элементы `CardViev` имели  высоту `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` а не ту которую имели элементы на позиции которого они раньше стояли?
Код элемента

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_farm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:text="Назва препарату"
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:id="@+id/doza"
                    android:text="Доза"
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/group"
                android:text="Група препаратів"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#ffeb3b"
                android:background="#3f51b5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recipe"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <org.sufficientlysecure.htmltextview.HtmlTextView
                android:id="@+id/inform"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

и код  адаптера

```
public class RecycleViewAdapterFarmacopedia extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapterFarmacopedia.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mDoza = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mRecipe = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mInform = new ArrayList<>();
    //private ArrayList<String> mImageUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecycleViewAdapterFarmacopedia (Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mNames, ArrayList<String> mDoza, ArrayList<String> mGroup, ArrayList<String> mRecipe, ArrayList<String> mInform/**, ArrayList<String> mImageUrl*/) {
        this.mNames = mNames;
        this.mDoza = mDoza;
        this.mGroup = mGroup;
        this.mRecipe = mRecipe;
        this.mInform = mInform;
        //this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_for_recyclelist, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        /*Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImageUrl.get(position))
                .into(holder.image);*/
        holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));
        holder.doza.setText(mDoza.get(position));
        holder.group.setText(mGroup.get(position));
        holder.recipe.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.card_farm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
               boolean purchased = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).getBoolean(AppConstants.PRODUCT_ID_BOUGHT, false);
               boolean subscribed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).getBoolean(AppConstants.PRODUCT_ID_SUBSCRIBE, false);
               if (!purchased && !subscribed) {
                   holder.recipe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   holder.recipe.setText(R.string.recipe);
               }else{
                   holder.recipe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   holder.recipe.setText(mRecipe.get(position));
               }
               holder.inform.setHtml(mInform.get(position));
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return mNames.size();
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        HtmlTextView inform;
        //ImageView image;
        TextView name, doza, group, recipe;
        CardView card_farm;
        public ViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            doza = itemView.findViewById(R.id.doza);
            group = itemView.findViewById(R.id.group);
            recipe = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe);
            inform = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inform);
            //image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageurl);
            card_farm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_farm);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фишка `RecyclerView` и `ViewHolder` в том, что holder'ы переиспользуются, а не создаются заново для каждого элемента списка, то есть установив у какого-нибудь холдера видимость каких-нибудь элементов, при его переиспользовании во время прокрутки, даже после заполнения контентом, элементы, ранее помеченные как видимые, так и останутся видимыми. Можно в `onBindViewHolder` изначально программно устанавливать для таких элементов видимость в `GONE` и при клике показывать, но при этом при прокрутке вниз/вверх, ранее расширенные карты могут снова сжаться до первоначального вида, если холдер для них будет пересоздан.

**UPDATE**

У вас как я вижу, в принципе уже есть строка кода скрывающая элемент `holder.recipe.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`, однако, тут нужно устанавливать `View.GONE`, так как `View.INVISIBLE` делает элемент невидимым, но при этом место под него будет выделено.

Comment: Напишите точнее код.  Если я понял Вас правильно, вы предлагаете все элементы которые находятся в CardView сделать под  setVisibility(View.GONE) вот так?

Comment: зачем все элементы, только те, которые вы при нажатии на карточку делаете видимыми.

Comment: Ну да то есть `holder.recipe.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: @VladBulan, да, обновил ответ. Просто, вы использовали View.INVISIBLE.

Comment: На элементы в xml разметки видимость ставить какую либо не нужно?